# Debian 9 Load installer problem

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I just downloaded Debian 9 from the official site:
[debian.org](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/)
and wanted to install it on my computer. I used Linux Live USB Creater and WinToFlash to load it on my USB stick. Before I checked the MD5 with WinMD5free and it says 'MATCHED'.

So I start the setup and after selecting language and keyboard settings I get the Load installer error.

> There was a problem reading data from the CD-ROM. Please make sure it is in the drive. If retrying does not work, you should check the integrity of your CD-ROM.

If I run 'Check the CD-ROM(s) integrity' the message:

> The This file failed the MD5 checksum verification. Your CD-ROM or this file may have been corrupted.

But WinMD5 said it is okay...So why I get this message? I know they had problems with Debian 9 and they released 9.1.0 hotfix.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest you'd check the checksum of what was actually written to the USB stick (it's possible you have a faulty USB stick).

Comment: I tried already a different one

Comment: And what happened? A failing self-check is a very bad sign. Which installer image did you download? Please provide its link and checksum as computed by you. Debian installer images are supposed to be written straight to the stick without any fancy software, https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.html.en recommends http://sf.net/projects/win32diskimager/, try that if you really need to use a Win32 system for writing the image.

Comment: Thank you for your repy. I downloaded from [link](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/bt-cd/) the file debian-9.1.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso.torrent and after download I checked the MD5 from this file with the file debian-9.1.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso from [link] (https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/bt-cd/MD5SUMS), NOTE: I download and prepare the ISO on a Win10 64bit system

Comment: Okay I found the solution....I burned it with CDBurnerXP and everything is working fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with detecting the usb devices. I tried 2 different usb-sticks and none of them worked. So I tried to install it with a CD-ROM. Downloaded the file above, burned .iso with CDBurnerXP and it is working!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using unetbootin ( https://unetbootin.github.io/ )to create your USB stick.  Worst case, if you have sufficient bandwidth you could perform a netinstall of Debian from a Live USB created with unnetbootin.

Comment: Debian docs recommend the `win32diskimager` tool to create a bootable USB from   windows.

Comment: Debian specifically warns against using unetbootin to create a USB install.